# Abstraction over a sequence of types

Tags: scala, scalaz, shapeless

Assuming we have a type `T[A,B]`, can we express the following type constraint,  let's call it `HT`:

every type satisfying `HT` must be of form `T[P1, P2] :: T[P2, P3] :: T[P3, P4] :: ... :: T[PN-1, PN] :: HNil`

for some `type x = P1 :: P2 :: ... :: PN :: HNil`.

I am trying to find an abstraction over a typed sequential processing pipeline.

Comment: Just thinking aloud, but perhaps you should model the pipes explicitly and not just the processing steps. Because the pipes have the same type at either 'end'...

Comment: Inheritance? All your P1, P2, ... PN classes could inherit from the same super class so you'd use T[PSUPER,PSUPER]

Comment: @rspencer, I assume the OP wants to know that the second type parameter of the type of one list element is the same type as the first type parameter of the type of the next list element. Not just that they're all T[Px, Py] for some x and y.

Comment: @Paul - Ah, missed the correspondence between the HList element types. I see that this is now trying to make the output match the input in the stages of a pipeline. Interesting problem, will have to give it some more thought!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most convenient way to do this kind of thing is usually to write your own type class. Here's a quick working sketch:

```
import shapeless._

trait T[I, O] extends (I => O)

trait Pipeline[P <: HList] {
  type In
  type Out
  type Values <: HList
}

object Pipeline {
  type Aux[P <: HList, In0, Out0, Values0 <: HList] = Pipeline[P] {
    type In = In0; type Out = Out0; type Values = Values0
  }

  def apply[P <: HList](
    implicit pipeline: Pipeline[P]
  ): Aux[P, pipeline.In, pipeline.Out, pipeline.Values] = pipeline

  implicit def onePipeline[I, O]: Aux[T[I, O] :: HNil, I, O, I :: O :: HNil] =
    new Pipeline[T[I, O] :: HNil] {
      type In = I
      type Out = O
      type Values = I :: O :: HNil
    }

  implicit def longerPipeline[I, O, P <: HList, Out0, Values0 <: HList](
    implicit pipeline: Aux[P, O, Out0, Values0]
  ): Aux[T[I, O] :: P, I, Out0, I :: Values0] =
    new Pipeline[T[I, O] :: P] {
      type In = I
      type Out = Out0
      type Values = I :: Values0
    }
}
```

And then (reformatted for clarity):

```
scala> Pipeline[T[String, Int] :: T[Int, Char] :: HNil]
res5: Pipeline[T[String, Int] :: T[Int, Char] :: HNil] {
  type In = String
  type Out = Char
  type Values = String :: Int :: Char :: HNil
} = Pipeline$$anon$2@38fd077c

scala> Pipeline[T[String, Int] :: T[Char, Char] :: HNil]
<console>:19: error: could not find implicit value for parameter
  pipeline: Pipeline[[T[String, Int] :: T[Char, Char] :: HNil]
              Pipeline[T[String, Int] :: T[Char, Char] :: HNil]
                      ^
```

The invalid pipeline doesn't compile, and for the valid one we get the endpoints and intermediate values correctly inferred.